# Nexus 7: micro usb port broken

Tags: usb, battery, nexus-7, charging

I have a 2012 nexus 7, its a beast of a device.
But unfortunately the usb port of the device is broken.

Is there any way I can charge the batteries my beloved nexus? I have opened it up, and removed its batteries from the wire that was attached to the socket. I have an external changer as well, I could try attaching the wires which are on the batteries to the external charger, but its a bit risky.

I know i could get the usb port & headphone socket for it and replace it, but it costs 75$, if i am spending that much money on an old nexus i could go n get nexus 7 2013.

So, is there any other way I can charge the batteries of the nexus? Apart from the batteries the device works well, and I hate to see the beast of an nVidia tegra 3 go to waste like that.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with the Nexus 7. The port loosens way too easily making it hard to charge. Often this happens if you have the charger in and you pull Nexus and it twists in the socket. We can only hope Nexus improves this in the future. There are videos on line to replace the port. Like I said, its a common problem. The replacement is fairly involved and you may want to try a professional if you don't feel comfortable with the layers involved in the tear down to get to the port.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give details on "broken" in which way, but if it's about not charging,
or having a flaky connection when charging:

There seems to be a **common problem** with the **micro-USB port** speciffically **in phones**.

It is very simple, but **not** so **simple to detect**.
The problem is dust on the "back wall" of the connector on the phone.

If you look into it, wou will just **see** this "wall", with **no dust**.
Chances are that there is dust - like fiber collected from cloth of paper in your pocket over time, but **perfectly compressed** by hundreds of connecting cycles. Looks just like a perfect surface (in the limited visibility situation in the socket).

So please do not make an assumption about it and **give it a try** - use a **needle** to scratch that "wall", and see how it reacts.
Next part may be easy, surprising, and fun!

(take care of unpowering the device it you use a conducting tool)

Comment: its broken in a way that it cant be fixed unless usb port itself is replaced :)

Comment: @2am Hmm... "too broken, then"... need to look for a better place for that answer ;)

Comment: yepp. I am looking for some guy who knows ICs, some electical engineer, because there was a chip attached to the battery, which had wires going to a rather unusual port.

Comment: Ask at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/! At least if you know what you need.

Comment: Sounds like it was the battery charging control, which is part of the battery pack, where it can measure the batteries temparature. That would mean you need a new battery pack.

Comment: oh, i didnt know there was a stackexchange about electronics as well, thanks mate :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14103/discussion-between-2am-and-volker-siegel)

Comment: http://www.electronicspoint.com/threads/nexus-7-battery-eliminator.264487/  These guys have eliminated the battery altogether :O

Comment: @2am Take a look here regarding charging the battery directly. And note and understand the warnings. These batteries do start to suddenly burn in an unpleasent way if mistreated - and we're probably mistreating them, as long as not all pins on the battery connector are handled. The charger is inside the battery pack mostly to have a chanche to do a "emergency shutdown" of the battery if it goes hot.   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2137652